# OmniAuth Action Controller Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm using the OmniAuth gem with my Rails Application to allow users to add their Facebook account to the application, and I'm following Ryan Bates' Tutorial, but I continue to get this Rails error.

undefined local variable or method `authentications_url' for #

Here's the controller for the authentications:

```
    class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
    end

    def create
      auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'],auth['uid'])
     flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    end

   def destroy
      @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
      @authentication.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
      redirect_to authentications_url
   end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you that your route does not exist.  Run `rake routes` at the command prompt and see if you have an `authentications` route

From the [ASCIIcasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) version of that episode, your `config/routes.rb` file should look similar to this:

```
ProjectManage::Application.routes.draw do |map|  
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'  
  devise_for :users  
  resources :projects  
  resources :tasks  
  resources :authentications  # <-- This is the one you're missing
  root :to => 'projects#index'  
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me tremendously.

Comment: Glad to hear it, please accept the answer by checking the checkmark if it answered your question